# Jenkins not working

Tags: jenkins, hudson, jenkins-plugins, hudson-plugins

I added some new tasks, then I am getting error while run job or change the job configuration and save.

> Status Code: 500
>       Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to serialize hudson.model.AbstractProject#blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding for
>   class hudson.model.FreeStyleProject
>       Stacktrace:
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to serialize
>   hudson.model.AbstractProject#blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding for
>   class hudson.model.FreeStyleProject
>         at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:719)
>         at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:770)
>         at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:241)
>         at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
>         at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:677)
>         at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:770)
>         at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:583)
>         at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:214)
>         at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:45)
>         at winstone.ServletConfiguration.execute(ServletConfiguration.java:248)
>         at winstone.RequestDispatcher.forward(RequestDispatcher.java:333)
>         at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:376)
>         at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:95)
>         at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:87)
>         at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
>         at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
>         at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:48)
>         at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
>         at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
>         at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
>         at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
>         at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:164)
>         at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
>         at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
>         at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:50)
>         at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
>         at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
>         at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
>         at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
>         at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
>         at winstone.RequestDispatcher.forward(RequestDispatcher.java:331)
>         at winstone.RequestHandlerThread.processRequest(RequestHandlerThread.java:227)
>         at winstone.RequestHandlerThread.run(RequestHandlerThread.java:150)
>         at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
>         at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
>       Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to serialize hudson.model.AbstractProject#blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding for
>   class hudson.model.FreeStyleProject
>         at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter$2.writeField(RobustReflectionConverter.java:208)
>         at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter$2.visit(RobustReflectionConverter.java:176)
>         at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.PureJavaReflectionProvider.visitSerializableFields(PureJavaReflectionProvider.java:135)
>         at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.doMarshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:161)
>         at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.marshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:102)
>         at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:69)
>         at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:58)
>         at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:43)
>         at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.start(TreeMarshaller.java:82)
>         at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.marshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:37)
>         at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.marshal(XStream.java:898)
>         at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.marshal(XStream.java:887)
>         at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.toXML(XStream.java:860)
>         at hudson.XmlFile.write(XmlFile.java:183)
>         at hudson.model.AbstractItem.save(AbstractItem.java:473)
>         at hudson.model.Job.save(Job.java:154)
>         at hudson.model.AbstractProject.save(AbstractProject.java:273)
>         at hudson.model.AbstractProject.makeDisabled(AbstractProject.java:679)
>         at hudson.model.AbstractProject.doDisable(AbstractProject.java:2038)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
>         at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:288)
>         at org.kohsuke.stapler.interceptor.RequirePOST$Processor.invoke(RequirePOST.java:29)
>         at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InterceptedFunction.invoke(Function.java:389)
>         at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:151)
>         at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:90)
>         at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:111)
>         at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
>         at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:677)
>         ... 39 more
>       Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.StreamException:  : No space left on device
>         at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.QuickWriter.flush(QuickWriter.java:77)
>         at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.QuickWriter.write(QuickWriter.java:37)
>         at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.PrettyPrintWriter.endNode(PrettyPrintWriter.java:313)
>         at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.WriterWrapper.endNode(WriterWrapper.java:37)
>         at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.path.PathTrackingWriter.endNode(PathTrackingWriter.java:48)
>         at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter$2.writeField(RobustReflectionConverter.java:205)
>         ... 69 more
>       Caused by: java.io.IOException: No space left on device
>         at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
>         at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:318)
>         at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
>         at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:291)
>         at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:295)
>         at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
>         at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
>         at java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(BufferedWriter.java:254)
>         at hudson.util.AtomicFileWriter.flush(AtomicFileWriter.java:90)
>         at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.QuickWriter.flush(QuickWriter.java:75)
>         ... 74 more

Comment: Is this all of the stacktrace?

Answer (score 6):

Reason: Disk was full,

Solution: Deleted some of unwanted folders, not only from .jenkins folder, any where in parent folder or any where in file system.

Comment: Glad you found it! You should accept your own answer so this doesn't appear to be an unanswered question.